# Can’t create access type to access an array of integer

Tags: ada

Creating access type of array of integer gives an error. Below is my code, please help me to fix it.

```
procedure arry_point is
   type arr is array(1..5) of integer;
   obj:aliased arr;
   type my_access1 is access all arr;
   var1:my_access1:=obj'Access;-- this is good
   ii: aliased array(1..5)of integer
   type my_access is access all ii; --this is bad but how can i create access type for ii ?
   var:my_access:=ii'access;   ---?
begin
   null;
end arry_point;
```

Comment: ii is of a new array type (an anonymous array type), so it would be a mistake for my_access to point to it. It's not obvious what you are trying to achieve, i.e. why you aren't declaring ii as an arr, so I'll stop there.

Comment: @BrianDrummond i am trying to create access type without using type ?

Comment: Read up on "anonymous access types" and "unchecked_access" to see if they might fit what you are doing. But you still haven't said what you are trying to achieve, only how you are trying to achieve it. There are usually better ways to do things than access types.

Comment: @BrianDrummond i am new to ada and leaning it .i am trying to access array of 5 integer using access type?

Comment: Declare a new array type and declare `ii` to be of that type.  Or declare `ii` to be of type `arr`.  I don't know what your reasons are for wanting to avoid declaring a new array type, but there really isn't a good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type My_Access is access ...` what? The answer is, it has to be a type name (strictly a *subtype_indication*, see [ARM 3.10(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-10.html#p3).

When you say `ii: aliased array(1..5) of integer` you’re creating an array of an anonymous type; this means you can’t supply the type name to complete the access type definition.

You could imagine a language (C++?) in which you could say

```
type My_Access is access all Type_Of (II);
```

or, perhaps,

```
type My_Access is access all II'Type;
```

but neither of those is possible in Ada. I suspect the reason is that there wouldn’t be any point, because in Ada types are not equivalent even if they have the same structure:

```
 1. procedure SG is
 2.    A : array (1 .. 5) of Integer := (others => 0);
 3.    B : array (1 .. 5) of Integer;
 4. begin
 5.    B := A;
            |
    >>> expected type of B declared at line 3
    >>> found type of A declared at line 2

 6. end SG;
```